# get all facebook contacts with swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all my facebook contacts. With this code managed to catch however I can not bring the phone information and email contacts. This is my code:

```
let params = ["fields": "first_name, last_name, name, email, picture, phone"]
                let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/taggable_friends", parameters: params);

                request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        self.appDelegate.dismissHUD()
                        let resultdict = result as! NSDictionary
                        self.fbContact = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as! NSArray
                        print(self.fbContact)
                        self.loadData()
                    } else {
                        self.appDelegate.showError("Time Out")
                    }
```

it returns this dictionary:

```
(
        {
        "first_name" = xxxx;
        id = "AaJRSpI-fYgIaPMaJCHEgCHB59aRecZbRSx0BrvDR_bZV-1W873iXn34kU940C_hc-TaoPnuFDfsJbBYtDSAFWiBfGWBXbxOja0c3NIHhyFqoQ";
        "last_name" = xxxx;
        name = "xxxx xxxx";
        picture =         {
            data =             {
                "is_silhouette" = 0;
                url = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/10351160_1463351673922060_1213695234585630315_n.jpg?oh=4c3b52137fc70b5743c7d00c2d=56ECD8DC&__gda__=1456979546_a879ab411cdf61e9293f27f70cd43bdd";
            };
        };
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a facebook Graph API limitation. There is some limitations on the data you can get depending on the role you are. You cannot get your friends email or phone using Graph API.

Comment: Only if the friends from the user are also users of your application. You can only get this data from the users who authorized your app. Valeu Breno!

Answer (score 0):

`taggable_friends` can ONLY be used for tagging, it does not include any other data. You can only get additional data of friends who authorized your App too.

Btw, you can´t even get the phone of the authorized user, there´s no way to get it at all. And for the email, you have to authorize a user with the `email` permission.

In general, you can´t get any data of users who did not authorize your App, for privacy reasons.